# JMS (Java Message Service)

Tags: java, jms, producer-consumer

I was reading about JMS [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html) and I thought "I've written a simpler consumer/producer before...". Am I being naïve about the power of JMS? I think something simpler is a better implementation of working through a Web Service to grab an `XML` document and pop it in a `Queue`.  Is the approach I am taking incorrect?

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. Have you tried some implementation of your own?  And what Queue are you taking about with context to your web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont need highly scalable and configurable distributed components with guaranteed delivery over multiple server crashes and automatic enrollment/commit/rollback in various transactions along with dead letter queue management, then yes a simple Queue with custom MessageProducer and MessageConsumer is probably a correct approach.

The golden rule: if the complexity of implementing a simple solution using stack X nullifies the benefits of using stack X, don't use it.